# How to open localhost from another device on my network?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I made Sinatra small App to help me transfer files from my phone to my pc and now I'm trying to open it from my phone and can't access, what should i do?

Comment: `localhost` refers to the devise you are using. You have to use the PCs host name or IP address.

Comment: @Stefan: won't help if the server binds to loopback :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev good point, you have to bind to 0.0.0.0. This is also Sinatras default when running in a non-development environment.

Comment: @Stefan thanks man, it worked

Answer (score 4):

I use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)

```
$ ngrok http 3000
```

And it gives me

```
ngrok by @inconshreveable                                                                                                                       (Ctrl+C to quit)

Tunnel Status                 online
Version                       2.1.3
Region                        United States (us)
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040
Forwarding                    http://320e69c0.ngrok.io -> localhost:3000
Forwarding                    https://320e69c0.ngrok.io -> localhost:3000
```

Then I can use one of those ngrok.io urls anywhere in the internet.

Answer (score 0):

start your application with -o 0.0.0.0 option.
type `ipconfig` (windows) or `ifconfig` (linux/mac) in your terminal application and get local ip address of your host device (e.g. `192.168.1.x`). then on your phone, open browser and type that ip (`192.168.1.x`) and port (by default `4567`, full form `192.168.1.x:4567`) to access your sinatra application.